# How to copy last 13 characters of a string?

Tags: character, notepad++, extract

In Notepad++ I have a list of entries and at the end of each entry is a phone number (with dashes, 12 characters total).  How do I go about either removing all the text before the number or copy/cut the number from the end of the entry for multiple entries? Thanks!

i.e.
1   $1,300 Deposit $1,300 Available 12/15/16 2050 Hurricane Shoals  678-790-0986

2   7 $1,400 Deposit $1,400 Available 12/22/16 1453 Alamein Dr  404-294-6441

3   $1,500 - $1,590 Not Income Based  /  Deposit $1,500 - $1,590  678-328-7952

Comment: Don't forget to tag the programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*([\d-]{12})$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>